# Exchange 2010, Event 3145 MSEXCHANGEREPL error

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-migration, windows-event-log

### Server 2008 R2 Exchange 2010 SP1

receiving another error in the event log:

---

Event 3154, msexchangeRepl

```
> Active Manager failed to mount database Mailbox Database 1037838543 on server WIN2K8EX.JEWELS.LOCAL. Error: An Active Manager operation failed with a transient error. Please retry the operation. Error: Database action failed with transient error. Error: A transient error occurred during a database operation. Error: MapiExceptionNetworkError: Unable to make admin interface connection to server. (hr=0x80040115, ec=-2147221227)
Diagnostic context:
    ......
    Lid: 12696   dwParam: 0x6D9      Msg: EEInfo: Generation Time: 2011-03-21 17:37:36:276
    Lid: 10648   dwParam: 0x6D9      Msg: EEInfo: Generating component: 2
    Lid: 14744   dwParam: 0x6D9      Msg: EEInfo: Status: 1753
    Lid: 9624    dwParam: 0x6D9      Msg: EEInfo: Detection location: 501
    Lid: 13720   dwParam: 0x6D9      Msg: EEInfo: Flags: 0
    Lid: 11672   dwParam: 0x6D9      Msg: EEInfo: NumberOfParameters: 4
    Lid: 8856    dwParam: 0x6D9      Msg: EEInfo: prm[0]: Unicode string: ncalrpc
    Lid: 8856    dwParam: 0x6D9      Msg: EEInfo: prm[1]: Unicode string: 
    Lid: 12952   dwParam: 0x6D9      Msg: EEInfo: prm[2]: Long val: -1988875570
    Lid: 12952   dwParam: 0x6D9      Msg: EEInfo: prm[3]: Long val: 382312662
    Lid: 24060   StoreEc: 0x80040115
    Lid: 23746  
    Lid: 31938   StoreEc: 0x80040115
    Lid: 19650  
    Lid: 27842   StoreEc: 0x80040115
    Lid: 20866
```

---

read this http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchange2010/thread/aff2fa90-3b1a-4610-a091-27f9880da8e7/

however it did not work.

whenever i tried to run Disable-CmdletExtensionAgent "Admin Audit Log Agen" I receive the error

The specified agent can't be disabled

```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Disable-CmdletExtensionAgent], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 75DDD1AB,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ProvisioningAgentTasks.DisableCmdletExtensionAgen
   t
```

any help with this error is appreciated as well

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to see if your Microsoft Exchange System Attendant service, Information Store service,  and Exchange Service host service are running.

Sometimes, these can fail to correctly start because of invalid TCP/IP settings on a NIC. Validate that all your NICs are configured correctly, and disable any that aren't being used.

Comment: all services are started , tcp/ip settings for ip4 on the NIC are valid. dns points to my dns server, static ip is set with subnet and correct gateway.

Comment: What I've found, is that if I set the Microsoft Exchange File Distribution Service and the Microsoft Exchange Replication Services to Startup Automatic (Delayed), the Event ID's 1028 and 3154 went away.  Very wierd.  If this is the case, why doesn't Microsoft set that by default?  - i read this on another forum. i'm going to give that a try

Comment: Also, play with IPv6. Enabling/disabling. These services are fairly picky about those things, but don't give good logs as to why they refuse to automatically start or run correctly.

Comment: the last comment I left seemed to have done the trick, by setting them to a delayed start I do not see the event log error anymore.

Comment: on to the next error - probably see ur next solution there! thanks again

Answer (score 1):

What I've found, is that if I set the Microsoft Exchange File Distribution Service and the Microsoft Exchange Replication Services to Startup Automatic (Delayed), the Event ID's 1028 and 3154 went away. Very wierd. If this is the case, why doesn't Microsoft set that by default?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have enabled IPv6 on Exchange server, you can use following steps;

1. Affected server > Windows Key+R > ncpa.cpl
2. Right click >Properties.
3. Check if IPv6 IS selected

Also check [following link](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/161595-solve-error-mapiexceptionnetworkerror-unable-to-mount-database-hr-0x80040115-ec-2147221227) for more information about the error.